# Set Cache-Control on Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: php, google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket with public images that are frequently updated and would like to disable the default cache duration of 3600. (E.g. "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform")

Can the Cache-Control be set on a file while uploading it with PHP?

Is there a way to set the default Cache-Control for all future files in the bucket (like with ACL that all files are public)?

Right now I can only set it Cache-Control with gsutil and only for files currently on storage.

Comment: While not documented, you can set Cache-Control via stream context, the same as you do with Content-Type (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/advanced#permissions_caching_and_metadata_options).

Comment: @Mars I'm sorry but I cannot get this to work with Cache-Control (however it does work with Content-Type as you wrote). It would have been a great solution.

Comment: Could you please file a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=Language%3DPHP thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example I created after finding your question. In the below I want the file I upload to not be cached:

```
$this->bucket->upload(
  $content,
  [
    'name' => $name,
    'metadata' => [
      'cacheControl' => "public, max-age=0"
    ]
  ]
);
```

I worked this out by:

1. Going to the repo: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-storage
2. That lead to the official docs: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs
3. I found the PHP reference: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.122.0/storage/storageclient
4. Which contained the bucket's `upload` reference: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.122.0/storage/bucket?method=upload
5. Which recommends using the JSON API reference for metadata https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#request-body
6. Which links to a rfc spec doc for cache control https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2

All of the above were useful resources, but hopefully my answer will be more succinct for future "Googlers".

Comment: Boom. Instant updates now using `'cacheControl' => "public, max-age=0"`. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, great example and great research.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the Cache-Control while uploading an object - I suggest you use gsutil -D to see an example of the request it generates to do this, and then translate that to PHP:

```
gsutil -D -h Cache-Control:"Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" \
    cp file gs://your-bucket/file
```

There's no way to set a default Cache-Control for the bucket.

Comment: Thanks! But I think there is a typo in the command. The -D flag got me to think that the only solution to set Cache-Control on the server (with PHP) is via a JSON PATCH request to the Cloud Storage.

Comment: @mike-schwartz Are there any plans to be able to set a default? Just as we can set default permissions...

Comment: @Jaap - sorry, no current plans to add the ability to set a default Cache-Control.

Comment: @mike-schwartz, I had trouble specifying cache control during upload with signed urls.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223966/google-cloud-storage-set-default-cache-control

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the gcloud-node library. You might try adding a gcloud-node tag to this stackoverflow question, so someone more knowledgeable about that library might see it.