# Google Cloud Storage set cache-control with signed urls upload

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

We're using signed urls to upload from the browser. I haven't been able to figure out how to set the cache-control header while uploading.

We're using the gcloud-node library to sign urls:

```
var bucket = gcs.bucket('mybucket');
var file = bucket.file('image.jpg');

var expireDate = new Date
expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);

file.getSignedUrl({
  action: 'write',
  expires: expireDate,
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
}, function (err, signedUrl) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('SignedUrl error', err);
  } else {
    console.log(signedUrl);
  }
});
```

How do I set the Cache-Control headers while uploading a file to GCS?
The code to upload is running in the browser:

```
var signedUrl = ...; // get from nodejs server
var fileList = this.files;

var file = fileList[0];

jQuery.ajax({
  url: signedUrl,
  type: 'PUT',
  data: file,
  processData: false,
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
})
```

Comment: @mike-schwartz, can a cache-control be set using signed urls?

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, but the documentation is terrible. First you need to setup CORS on the bucket you're uploading to with:

```sh
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://bucket-name
```

Where `cors.json` contains something like:

```
[{
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
    "method": ["GET", "PUT", "POST"],
    "origin": [
        "http://localhost:3000"
    ],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Cache-Control"]
}]
```

"Cache-Control" needs to be listed in the "responseHeader" field. Then upload like you normally would, but set the `Cache-Control` header. Using `fetch` it would be:

```
fetch(uploadUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: blob,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': blob.type,
        'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31536000',
    },
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I have to use the `gsutil` command like this `gsutil -h "Cache-Control:no-cache"`. It really would be nice to be able to set this header in a regular fetch / curl request upload.

Comment: "This is possible, but the documentation is terrible" applies to way too many of GCP's features.

Answer (score -1):

the snippet you have is getting a signed url.  when you upload (insert) the object into GCS, you should be able to set it via the API:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

Comment: Signed urls are not the same as the json api.

Comment: Jaap, could I trouble you to clarify the question? The original question was "How do I set the Cache-Control headers while uploading a file to GCS?".  But the snippet you showed is Signed URL.  To set the Cache-Control header when uploading the file to GCS, you should look at the objects.insert API, which has a property for "cacheControl".

Comment: You are right, I've updated the question to show how I use the signed url to upload the file.

Comment: thnx ;) not sure who down voted the response since it was well within the original ask.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a way to pass in cache control header when uploading from a signed-url. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs