# Why does Cache-Control fail for signed URLs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a signed URL containing a `cache-control` header using signed URLs V2.

When I create a URL like this, the URL is valid and works.

```
        String signature = "PUT" + "\n" +
                "\n" +
                contentType + "\n" +
                expiresWhen + "\n" +
                "x-goog-acl:public-read" + "\n" +
                path;
```

But when I add the `cache-control` header, I get 403 when trying to upload:

```
        String signature = "PUT" + "\n" +
                "\n" +
                contentType + "\n" +
                expiresWhen + "\n" +
                "cache-control:public,max-age=600" + "\n" +
                "x-goog-acl:public-read" + "\n" +
                path;
```

The only thing that I changed are the headers. The headers are alpha-sorted, contain no spaces, and are separated with "\n", so all requirements should be met. Or did I make a mistake here? I assume `public,max-age` must stay in this order and not be sorted. Probably fine if specified the same when uploading.

Then I found this question [Google Cloud Storage set cache-control with signed urls upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223966/google-cloud-storage-set-cache-control-with-signed-urls-upload) but I assume it doesn't apply because we're uploading from a server, not from a browser. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Setting `cache-control` to 600 works for me when I add it to the request only, but apparently it cannot be part of the signature. Is this correct?

Comment: Signed URLs do not care if you are running in a browser or from a `curl` command provided that there is no CORS issue. If you are using a CDN, Cache-Control is ignored for signed URLs. When using a signed URL, you are the caller (client), not the server. Cache-Control is not something that the client manages. Therefore, don't try to set it as there is no point. You can set the Cache-Control header in Cloud Storage for the object, but I have not verified the results with signed URLs.

Comment: I cannot include `cache-control` in the signed URL, but if the client which sends it to GCS for an upload and adds `cache-control` to the call, it becomes part of the uploaded object. IMO this doesn't make sense, as the uploader can specify a property in my store, which I cannot control. Isn't controlling this what signed URLs are for?

Comment: No, cache-control is a server-side property sent to clients, not the other way around. Set cache-control on the object in Cloud Storage, not in the request to Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When signed URL handling is enabled on a backend, Cloud CDN gives special handling to requests with signed URLs. Specifically, requests with a Signature query parameter are considered signed. When such a request is received, Cloud CDN verifies the following:

The HTTP method is GET or HEAD.
The Expires parameter is set to a future time.
The request's signature matches the signature computed using the named key.

If any of these checks fails, a 403 Forbidden response is served.

As we read with the John Hanley s comment, If you are using a CDN, Cache-Control is ignored for signed URLs.
I attach the next link:

https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cdn