# Add cache headers to all new assets in a Google Cloud bucket

Tags: caching, google-cloud-storage

I know it's possible to add cache headers to existing Google Cloud bucket objects.

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Type:text/html" \
  -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600" \
  -h "Content-Disposition" gs://bucket/*.html
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta

This works for all existing files in the bucket but a **newly uploaded file will not have these caching** headers.

How do I tell Google to add this header to every new file added to the bucket?

FWIW: I am using Carrierwave with Fog in Rails but guess that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: This question was asked and answered previously at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406410/set-cache-control-on-google-cloud-storage-bucket/25407394

Comment: Thanks Mike, too bad Google does not support default headers.