# Setting Cache-Control TTL from PHP on a Google Cloud Storage object changes the wrong metadata

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

As recommended by Lighthouse, I am trying to set my images in Google Cloud Storage to a long TTL (the default is 1 hour, I'm trying to set one year). I can set it correctly from the command line, using something like this:

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public,max-age=31536000" gs://mybucket/myfolder/myfname.jpg
```

But what I need to do is to set it using PHP, which I'm doing using Google's recommended code looking like this:

```
$client = new Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient([
   'projectId' => "xxx",
   'keyFilePath' => "yyy.json",
        ]);
$bucket = $client->bucket($bucketname);
$object = $bucket->upload($data, ['name' => "$folder/$objectname"]);
$object->update(['metadata' => ['Cache-Control' => 'public,max-age=' . (3600 * 24 * 365)]]);
```

The trouble is that the data I provide goes not into the main Cache-Control metadata item, but into a separate "Custom metadata" item, which is not actually used by GCS when serving my file and is therefore useless.

The attached screenshot shows the effect on the metadata. Btw when done using the command line, it's the higher Cache-Control box (in grey on the screenshot) that gets filled in, which is the one that GCS uses when serving the file.

Any ideas on how to make the PHP work?

A couple of notes:

1. I think this may be the same issue as this one:
   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/721233
2. This question is
   similar to an old one here, but it's not identical and the answers
   there didn't work for me:
   [Set Cache-Control on Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406410/set-cache-control-on-google-cloud-storage-bucket)

[image: Metadata shown on console after update.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from a Google Cloud partner, it would appear that although you can't update the cache control after upload, you can set it at the time you upload the file. So the following code works (note also the use of `cacheControl` rather than `Cache-Control`):

```
$client = new Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient([
   'projectId' => "xxx",
   'keyFilePath' => "yyy.json",
        ]);
$bucket = $client->bucket($bucketname);
$object = $bucket->upload($data, [
   'name' => "$folder/$objectname",
   'metadata' => ['cacheControl' => 'public,max-age=' . (3600 * 24 * 365)]
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently it is not possible to set a `default metadata` value such as Cache-control by using PHP or any other options.We can only set value to `custom metadata` fields using [available options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata). Currently available option for `default cache control` is only by using `gsutil -h option` at the application level.

As you have mentioned, for the uploaded objects in cloud storage, it requires running a `gsutil setmeta -h` command.

There is an existing [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/285047342) for the same to achieve through UI.You may add your concern for the same using client API or may consider raising a new  [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) by describing your request in detail..

Comment: Sathi Aiswarya: thanks for answering, but: although it would be great to set this value by default, that's not what I'm asking here. The reason I'm asking is precisely that there isn't a way of setting it by default, so I'm trying to set it programmatically on each individual object. This is a documented PHP API which doesn't seem to be behaving as advertised - either that, or I'm misunderstanding the keys.

Comment: @xgretsch As the feature request mentioned if you want to update the default metadata for an existing object in the bucket, it requires running a gsutil setmeta command.

Comment: Certainly, if that feature request were implemented, it would be the best solution, removing altogether the need to set the metadata each time I upload an object. However, making the existing API work properly might be an easier fix, so I will probably do as you say and add a separate feature request. Thanks.